# passing (global) variable from one smarty template to another

Tags: php, templates, smarty, smarty2

I am using smarty version 2.6.26 and according to the docs by using {include 'file.tpl' scope='global'} or {include 'child_template.tpl' scope=parent} one should be able to access the variables contained in the child template and use them in the parent template.

as an example I have code like below in my child template:

```
  {capture assign="project_variable" name=project_data scope="global"}
  my text data here...
  {/capture}
```

The variable {$project_data} is available within this template now

In my parent (dashboard) template I am using:

```
 {include 'child_template.tpl' scope=global}
```

but if I try to use {$project_data} in the  parent template it comes out blank. 
so it appears the variable set in the child template is local only?

according to the documentation at:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl

"You can use all variables from the including template inside the included template".

what am I missing here?
thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it seems you cannot do this in Smarty2. I tried a few ways but it doesn't work.

There is no `scope` property in Smarty3. You looked at documentation of Smarty3 and you should look at [documentation for Smarty2](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/)

Comment: the document for smarty2 seems the same:

Comment: My mistake, however, the document for smarty2 seems the same:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl

quote:
"This means you can use all variables from the including template inside the included template".
or am I misinterpreting?

according to this :
http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=56673
one can reuse the variable like {$smarty.capture.project_data}
for smarty2, but I have not been able to get this to work either.

Comment: AHA!
I just tried the full path to the template:
{include file='/home/username/public_html/mysite/custom_templates/child.tpl}
and used {$smarty.capture.project_data} and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I was making the assumption that using {include file='mytemplate.tpl'} would find the "file"
however it did not work until I used the full absolute path such as:
{include file='/home/username/public_html/mysite/custom_template.tpl}
and getting the variable using the format: {$smarty.capture.myvariable_name}
so I answered my own question but Marcin got me on the right track so thanks for that!

I spoke too soon. it appears I can only capture static text and not a "{foreach}" loop
any ideas greatly appreciated